# PDF responsive zoom on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I'm trying to make a PDF's zoom always full width within an iframe, and on browser resize it re-calculates the PDF's zoom and sets it to 100% browser width.

The [pdf parameter](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) #view=Fit or #zoom=100 works on document ready, but I can't manage get it to refresh/recalculate this value when the browser is resized (preferably without losing the scroll position).

```html
<iframe id="readFrame" src="https://xxxxxx.pdf#view=Fit"></iframe>
```

note: I'm resizing the iframe like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});

$(window).resize(function() {

    var browser_viewportH = $(window).height();
    var browser_viewportW = $(window).width();

    var nav_height = $("#nav-bar").height() + $("#tempWrapper").height();
    var block_height = $("#blockContainer").height();

    var viewportH = browser_viewportH - (nav_height + block_height);

    $("#readFrame").css("height", viewportH);
});
```

Comment: I am not even having luck loading pdf inside an iframe. which browser are you using?

Comment: If your sole concern is not losing the scroll position and your iframe is on the same domain, you can communicate across the iframe to store the scroll position, reload, then restore it.

Comment: Could we possibly get a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) if anyone else comes across this problem.

The problem with using the pdf parameters is they don't work in Chrome and Firefox as these browsers have their own pdf viewers.

On the other hand, pdf.js is only fully supported in Chrome and Firefox and others have limited support but are functional other than <=IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you have a Typo on here:

```
$("#read iframe").css("height", viewportH);
```

Should be

```
$("#readFrame").css("height", viewportH);
```

As your iframe has the ID "readFrame", hasn't it`?

Comment: Sorry I was a bit unclear with that, either work as the iframe is within an id of #read. Fixed with edit.

Comment: mhm okay, i did the same some months ago with an iframe-based pdf-viewer. I just gave the iframe the css-property "height:100%" and adjusted only the width of the iframe on the resize-event of my window. Did you try this? At least it worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="readFrame" src="YOUR_PDF_PATH.pdf#view=Fit" style="width:100%;"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#readFrame').css('height',$(window).height());
</script>
```

you can use this, and this works on resize as well, and this doesn't lose your scroll height too when resized..